# How to check a paypal billing agreement status?

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

Now that I have set up Billing Agreements and Reference Transactions in my web application, I've been trying to find a way to check the availability of a Billing Agreement. Something like the "GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails" API call. i've found "GetBillingAgreementCustomerDetails" but it seems that this one doesn't return the agreement status, which is what I need. So my question is, is there a way to find out if the billing agreement related to one billing agreement id is still active?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a way by using BAUpdate API which have a field *BILLINGAGREEMENTSTATUS* in the response fields.

Thank you all anyway